# Pushforward formula for Lebesgue Stieltjes Measure

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, pushforward

I got to have this problem in my hand.

> **Problem**
>     Let $F: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an increasing, right continuous function, and let $\phi :\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous increasing invertible function. Let $\mu_F$ and $\mu_{F\circ \phi}$ be the Lebesgue-Stieljes measure associated to $F$ and $F\circ \phi$ respectively. Show that if $f\in L^1(\mu_F)$, then $f\circ \phi \in L^1(\mu_{F\circ \phi})$ and $$ \int f d\mu_F = \int f\circ \phi d\mu_{F\circ \phi}$$  **Hint**: It is enough to consider non-negative $f$ and to prove the inequality $\int f\circ \phi d\mu_{F\circ \phi}\leq \int f\mu_F$.

There were many situation I have studied this kind of problem and I was thinking of using simple function and generalize it to arbitrary $L^1$ functions. And I think the method just works here too. But I can not understand the hint on this problem. Because I started from simple, the hint for non negative function seems superfluous but makes sense. **But I don't know how to use the hint for inequality.**  I will be happy with any kind of hint or comment on it.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you prove the hint for positive functions, you show that $f\circ \phi \in L^1(\mu_{F\circ \phi})$, since you are taking absolute values in any case. 

The change of variables formula is, indeed, proven using simple functions.

Comment: @Dosidis  That make sense!  Thank you!   But I still don't know how to use the inequality....